# Keeping a bootstrap modal static

Tags: jquery

I created a modal that shows on load of the page but I am having problems deactivating the backdrop option. I actually made the modal a login form and want to keep it static by deactivating all other options, but I haven't been able to do that so far. Here is the JavaScript function

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#my-Modal').modal('show');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".show-modal").click(function() {
        $("#my-modal").modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        });
    });
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you make simple demo in [here](codepen.io) so people can understand lah

Answer (score 0):

In your code you specify in the first part

```
$('#my-Modal')
```

and in the second

```
$('#my-modal')
```

ID are case-sensitive.